# Laravel 5.1 ajax not working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

i am trying to submit login form using ajax in laravel but it seems to be ajax part not working. below is my login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>


<div class="secure">Secure Login form</div>
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'account/login','method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'myform')) !!}
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
     {!! Form::text('email','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'form-control span6','placeholder' => 'Email')) !!}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
  {!! Form::password('password',array('class'=>'form-control span6', 'placeholder' => 'Please Enter your Password')) !!}
  </div>
</div>
{!! Form::button('Login', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.send-btn').click(function(){ 
$val=$('input[name=email]').val();  
$token=$('input[name=_token]').val();
//alert($val+$token);
   $.ajax({
      url: '/account/login',
      type: "post",

      data: {'email':$('input[name=email]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });  


  }); 
});
</script>
```

route.php

```
Route::get('account/login', function() {
  return View::make('login');
});
Route::post('account/login', 'AccountController@login');
```

in controller

```
 public function login() {

    if(Request::ajax()) {
      $data = Input::all();
      print_r($data);

      die;
    }

    }
```

I have tried to alert input values in ajax part before success, it will print output but success alert wont work.

Comment: Is your ajax request being sent with X-Requeted-With header? If it's not, then Request::ajax() will fail

Comment: @MarounBaydoun. i followed http://tutsnare.com/post-data-using-ajax-in-laravel-5/ this tutorial. i am new to laravel

Comment: Inspect the server response in your browser console to see what kind of error is happening

Comment: Check if you get any errors (_using firebug_) when you submit the form.

Comment: @MarounBaydoun,yes .console error says Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]

Comment: Check the network inspector to know what the server response is for the Ajax request

Comment: @MarounBaydoun,404 error

Comment: Try having the url as account/login instead of /account/login in the ajax request

Comment: @MarounBaydoun,in newtwork inspector shows 500 internal server error

Comment: @MarounBaydoun,i am working in localhost xamp server in windows 7

Comment: var $val=$('input[name=email]').val();  invalid
var $token=$('input[name=_token]').val(); invalid var $val=$('input[name=email]').val(); valid
var $token=$('input[name=_token]').val(); valid 2nd Laravel 5 remove Input Input::all(); it use Request::all();

Comment: @tester, don't look for errors just in the console. Look for errors in the response from the AJAX request. Ajax requests can usually be found under the `xhr` tab of the network inspector. This will show you any php errors coming from your application.

Comment: $data = Input::all(); change to $data = Request::all(); and try now because Input::all does not exists in Laravel 5.1

Comment: @Jeemusu, i am looking into network inspect element

Comment: I will post here updated solution for you in ajax in 5 minutes

Comment: try this http://kopy.io/jJV12

Comment: @Rajlaksh,not working .same error

Comment: @tester let me rebuild whole Controller. Have you try using Jquery Form Plugin?

Comment: @nope.just as it what i have added in my question

Comment: @tester You will be getting error messages in the response to your ajax request. Look at the network tab and the reponse/preview should show you the errors.

Comment: also, have you added `use Request;` to the top of your class file?

Answer (score 1):

Though logging in users through AJAX is insecure, it can be done none-the-less:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'account/login','method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'myform')) !!}
    /**
     * Your Form
     */
    ...
    {!! Form::submit('Login', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The CSRF field will be automatically generated for you. The JavaScript part:

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'account/login',
                data: $('#myform').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });            
    })(window.jQuery);
</script>
```

That should do the trick for the HTML and JavaScript part. In Laravel 5.1 we can leverage Method Injection to receive the Input fields ([Request Object](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests)) like so:

```
<?php

namespace Blah\Blah;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AccountController
{
    ...

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            // Its AJAX!!
            return $request->all(); // All the Input fields
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the changes that I did to your code. Please check whether this method works or not.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
public function login() {

if(Request::ajax()) {
  $data = Request::all();
  return $data;

       }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but Laravel 5 removed Input::all();

Comment: Try installing this to help debug: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar - it is really great.Because you get 500 internal.

Comment: If you get a HTTP 500 error you need to look into the serverlogs what it caused. We don't have a glass globe.

Comment: Run this code what it return http://kopy.io/xcGmA opps i forget to put semicolon in return Response::json($array) line correct it by this return Response::json($array);

Comment: in Auth Middleware is set if ($request->ajax())  kill it.

Comment: @Rajlaksh.not working.i will try and if its works then i will tell you

Comment: have you pass _token in every request,reason is HTTP 500 throw

Comment: @jigsVirani 500 error means something is wrong in controller. I use ajax for posting and deleting item :)

Answer (score 0):

Token is required. Try add:

> headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token}

in your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: route,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {data : data}
});
```