# Laravel 5: Ajax Post 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to submit data to the database via ajax. The submit article page works fine without ajax. I've added `console.log()` just to see if anything is going through, but instead I'm getting this error:

> POST http://localhost/laravel-5/public/articles/create 500 (Internal Server Error)

What's wrong with my code? Is it the javascript or the controller?

EDIT: I'm getting this in `laravel.log`

> exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:53

Route

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

Controller

```
public function store(Requests\ArticleRequest $request)
    {

        $article = new Article($request->all());
        Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Article has been posted.',
        );
        return \Response::json($response);
    }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var body = $('#body').val();
        var published_at = $('#published_at').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/laravel-5/public/articles/create',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {title: title, body: body, published_at: published_at},
            success: function( data ) {
                $("#ajaxResponse").append(data.msg);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

View

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1>Write a New Article</h1>

<hr>

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'articles', 'id' => 'frm']) !!}
    <p>
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title') !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::label('body', 'Body:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('body') !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Date:') !!}
        {!! Form::input('date', 'published_at', date('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::submit('Submit Article', ['id' => 'submit']) !!}
    </p>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<h3 id="ajaxResponse"></h3>

@if($errors->any())
    <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/ArticleCreate.js') }}"></script>
```

});

Comment: Check your Laravel/server logs for details on what the 500 was caused by.

Comment: That's what I got `exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:53`

Comment: @Halnex, you need to set the token, let me edit the answer

Comment: Your session is over? Before this: Auth::user()->articles()->save($article); check if the session is alive with if(Auth::check()) { //here the code}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you make a request via POST to a resource controller, it automatically calls store method:

```
Verb    Path        Action  Route Name
----------------------------------
POST    /articles   store   articles.store
```

So, you just need to change ajax url to:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/laravel-5/public/articles',
```

When you need to send the session token, you can add a global meta-tag like this is you website:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, just add the token via ajax's headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

If you are using `Form::open()` function (LaravelCollective) it adds a hidden input with the token as value with the name `_token`. So, you can remove the meta-tag and edit your ajax's headers like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
        }
});
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I just check laravel logs and I'm getting this error `exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:53`

Comment: Thank you for downvote without a constructive comment about it :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Infact, I just upvoted you because your solution works and the other guys didn't mention I need the `meta` tag in my view. But both of you are correct.

Comment: The problem is not the downvote, it is when people doesn't say anything xD. But that's cool, glad to help you!

Comment: I just noticed something, after I added the `meta` tag to the view, I'm now seeing 2 values with the same token. The meta tag and a hidden input field with the name `_token` - both have the same value. Why am I seeing this? and why the ajax post wouldn't work without the meta tag even though the token already exists?

Comment: That is because you are creating an html via `\HTML::form` function, by this way implicitly the function add a hidden input with the token as value. See edited answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That also did it. So all I had to do was call the correct field.

Comment: The use of `<meta>` is just necessary if you are not using `HTML::form()` function that make it automatically for you. That is why people use `<meta>` just when they create a form manually without the hidden input over a an over again the app.

Comment: @manix.i am also facing same problem.i tried this example .even in this example also i am getting same error.if you know can you post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203564/ajax-post-not-working-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: I confirm in that the 2nd solution ('X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()) worked pretty well in Laravel 5.2 using Laravel Collective forms

Answer (score 3):

> That's what I got exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Htt‌​p\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:53

You're hitting Laravel's CSRF protection.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

You need to pass the hidden `_token` field's value. This can be done automatically on all jQuery-initiated AJAX requests by doing this in your application's JS:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').value()
        }
});
```

Or, you can manually fetch and pass the value of the `_token` hidden field in each of your AJAX calls.

Comment: Thank you, but I still need to answer a `meta` tag in my view. That sorted it all out.

Comment: @Halnex I think that documentation has changed a bit since I last used it. I've updated mine to a non-meta tag version which'd be my preference usually.

Answer (score 0):

I like to share this code to help someone to need ajax post and get with laravel

```
<<<<<<<<
POST
<<<<
<<look after @extends<<
<<look beforeSend: function (xhr) <<
<<look use Illuminate\Http\Request in Routes<< 
<<<------<<views\login\login.blade.php<<<<-----------<<<
@extends('cuerpito.web')
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
@section('content')
  <form action="#" id="logForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email." autocomplete="off">                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                         <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa tu Contraseña." autocomplete="off">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group formSubmit">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="feedbackSubmit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">Ingresar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#feedbackSubmit").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                url: '{{URL::route('login4')}}',
                type: "post",
                 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

        if (token) {
              return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        }
    },
                data: $("#logForm").serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        console.log(data);
                         } else {
                  console.log(data);
                    }//else 
                }//success
              });//ajax
            return false;
          });//feedbacksubmit
   });//document ready
 </script>  
  -------------0----------------------
  -------------0----------------------
<<<----<<app\Http\routes.php<<<<-----------<<<
 <?php
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 Route::post('login4', function()
{
    return 'Success! POST Ajax in laravel 5';
})->name('login4');

------------------0----------------------
------------------0----------------------
<<<<
Get
<<look after @extends<<
<<look beforeSend: function (xhr) <<
<<look use Illuminate\Http\Request in Routes<< 
<<<------<<views\login\login.blade.php<<<<-----------<<<
@extends('cuerpito.web')
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
@section('content')
<form action="#" id="logForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email." autocomplete="off">                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                         <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa tu Contraseña." autocomplete="off">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group formSubmit">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="feedbackSubmit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">Ingresar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </form>


  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#feedbackSubmit").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                url: '{{URL::route('login2')}}',
                type: "get",

                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
        if (token) {
              return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        }
    },    

                data: $("#logForm").serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data) {
                        obj = JSON.stringify(data, null, "    ");
                        var datito = JSON.parse(obj);
                        console.log(datito.response);
                        alert(datito.response);

                    } else {
                        console.log(data);
                    }//else 
                }//success
            });//ajax
            return false;
        });//feedbacksubmit
});//document ready
 </script> 
  -------------0----------------------
  -------------0----------------------
    <<<----<<app\Http\routes.php<<<<-----------<<<
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    Route::get('login2', 'WebController@login2')->name('login2');
  -------------0----------------------
  -------------0----------------------
    <<<----<<Http\Controllers\WebController.php<<<<-----------<<<
   public function login2(Request $datos) {
    if ($datos->isMethod('get')) {
        return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
    }
    return response()->json(['response' => 'This is post method']);
}

  -------------0----------------------
  -------------0----------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your URLs to the VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware. The URLs will be excluded from CSRF verification:

```
protected $except = [ "your url", "your url/abc" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for the sure shot answer ,here it is :
This error particularly occurs if you are missing csrf_token() in your code
Here is what I did,

```
<h6>ITEMS  ORDERED:<a href="#" id="{{$post->identifier}}" onclick="getcart(this.id)">CLICK HERE</a></h6>
<input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Now With Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getcart(val) {
  var alpha=val;
var token=document.getElementById('token').value;

$.ajax({
 type:'post',
 url:'/private/getcart',
 data:{'alpha':alpha,'_token': token},//this _token should be as it is 
 success:function (result) {
alert(result);
 }

});


}

</script>
```

In my laravel controller

```
public function getcart(Request $req)
{
  return response ("its");
}
```