# Internal Server Error Ajax request on Laravel 5.2.10 project

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel 5.2.10 project, I was trying to fetch some data via ajax but I'm getting an 500 error, and I can't find what I'm missing out.

This is part of my routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/videos', 'VideosController@index');
    Route::post('/videos/fetch', array('before' => 'ajax_check'), 'AjaxController@postFetch');
});
```

On my 'AjaxController.php' I've got this function

```
public function postFetch()
{
    //Process data and come up with $data
    return view('videos')->with('video_data', $data);
}
```

And this is the JS ajax call

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/videos/fetch",
    method: "POST",
    data: { url : url }
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
>   in RouteCollection.php line 219
>   at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
>   at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158

Comment: The MethodNotAllowed hints that your post route isn't being picked up. What does the middleware `web` do exactly? Your `postFetch()` method doesn't declare the`$data` variable, is that because you removed the code to simplify it? Also your post route isn't correct. It should be in the following format `Route::post('videos/fetch', array(
        'before'      => 'ajax_check',
        'uses'    => 'AjaxController@postFetch'
    ));`

Comment: $data is generation is omitted yes. middleware web manages the session info. I believe that the problem is at route.php but I'm not sure what is it, something regarding the way that POST data is managed.

Comment: Do you have route caching enabled? Does `php artisan routes` show the expected routes?

Comment: I found that it's a different error, there seems to be a "TokenMismatchException". Probably I have to add the csrf token to the ajax request, I'll try with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MethodNotAllowed` exception hints that your post route isn't being picked up. The format of your post route looks a little odd to me. It should be in the following format

`Route::post('videos/fetch', array( 'before' => 'ajax_check', 'uses' => 'AjaxController@postFetch' ));`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set permissions on your storage folder ? Please check your internal php server errors for more info with the command:

```
tail /var/log/php_errors.log
```

Comment: You can also check out this solution here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32257188/1763461)