# post 500 (internal server error) ajax though using csrf token in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

Though I am using `{{ csrf_field() }}` in my html file still got `POST http://localhost:8000/add_user 500 (Internal Server Error)`

here is my code

```
$.ajax({

    url:"/add_user",                       
    type: 'post',
    data: {_token : token, user_type_id : user_type_id,  full_name : full_name,  email : email, password : password,  username : username, date : date},
                        success:function(msg){

    $("#report").load(location.href + " #report");

   }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Ajax Post 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256969/laravel-5-ajax-post-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: Where do you get your token from? When using ajax (and not AXIOS) you need to include something like `var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');` in your javascript

Comment: @kerbholz...i have added `{{ csrf_field() }}` into my form

Comment: Your form doesn't get submitted when using ajax

Comment: @ kerbholz....I have done the delete and update part using same type of ajax function. But in add part this error shown...
It doesn't submitted I got that brother. But where is the error that I want to know :(

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with csrf token

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "url/update",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'id=' + id+ '&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
```

Answer (score 0):

provide your server router, it`s seem`s like you`ve missed this route request on your server