# 500 Internal Server Error though using csrf token in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

I am continuously getting the error `POST http://localhost:8000/live_datatable_search 500 (Internal Server Error)` where  `live_datatable_search` is the route name. Though I am using `{{ csrf_field() }}`.

Here is my script part

```
var search = $('#search').val();
        var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
        console.log(token);

        $.ajax({
                url:'/live_datatable_search',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                        search : search,
                        _token : token
                    },

                success:function(msg){
                    console.log(msg);

                    $("#report").html(msg);

                }
            });
```

Route

```
Route::post('live_datatable_search','HomeController@live_datatable_search');
```

Controller code

```
public function live_datatable_search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->search)
    {
        $search = Adminuser::select('adminuser.*', 'user_type.name as user_type')
            ->orderBy('adminuser.user_type_id')
            ->leftJoin('user_type', 'adminuser.user_type_id', '=', 'user_type.id')
            ->where('adminuser.full_name', 'like', '%'. $request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('adminuser.username', 'like', '%'. $request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('adminuser.email', 'like', '%'. $request->search.'%')
            ->get();

        if($search)
        {
            foreach ($search as $key => $value) {

                $trHTML += "<tr class='itemList' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'>";
                $trHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='id' value='" + $value->id +"'><input type='hidden' id='user_type_id' value='" + $value->user_type_id + "'>";
                $trHTML += "<td id='full_name'>" + $value->full_name + "</td>";
                $trHTML += "<td id='email'>" + $value->email + "</td>";
                $trHTML += "<td id='user_type'>" + $value->user_type + "</td>";
                $trHTML += "</tr>";

                echo $trHTML;

            }
        }
    }   
}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Did you not ask [the same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185723/post-500-internal-server-error-ajax-though-using-csrf-token-in-laravel)? Admittedly the endpoints are different, but the issue is the same.

Comment: check laravel log

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @ halfer...thanks ... I will rectify myself in future

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan... Ya.... Can't solve it yet :(

Comment: share controller's code for `live_datatable_search` ?

Comment: user2486 ... updated the post with controller and route...please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make alias of your mode and make a block of condition `orWhere`. Change in your laravel query, like below

```
$search = Adminuser::from("adminuser as au")
    ->leftJoin('user_type as ut', 'au.user_type_id', '=', 'ut.id')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->orwhere('au.full_name', 'like', '%'. $request->search.'%');
        $query->orWhere('au.username', 'like', '%'. $request->search.'%');
        $query->orWhere('au.email', 'like', '%'. $request->search.'%');
    })
    ->select('au.*', 'ut.name as user_type')
    ->orderBy('au.user_type_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: okay,.....I try step by step then....give you the feedback after sometime

Comment: @ user2486......whenever I use `Adminuser::all();` then it's ok....no error...but whenever i just add another query `select, join, where`... it gives the error

Comment: table name is ok. Is there any other issues?

Comment: `$users = DB::table('adminuser')->get();
            echo $users;`
Just use this and got error

Comment: we can remove the comments now it not related