# Unable to receive data using AJAX post in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to send some variables(data),one is the checkbox text, and other is the value in the textarea field to the controller in Laravel through ajax, below is the script:

```
<script>
    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        var aa=$(this).next('label').text();
        var bb=$('textarea#txt2').val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers:
                {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
        });
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/masterdata",
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: {aa,bb},
            success:function(){
            console.log(data);    
       }
        ,error:function(){ 
            console.log("Error!!!!");
       }    
    });
    });
    }); 
     </script>
```

On trying to retrieve the request values in the controller, only the request token gets displayed, and the ajax function doesn't display the success or error message either.What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked in your browser's development tools if the data gets sent to the server correctly?

Comment: I did, and I can see the token as well as some other request values, not the ones that I try sending through AJAX though.

Comment: Any error code you are getting ?? 500 ,405

Comment: Nope, 200, which should mean that the POST works fine right>

Comment: You can check my this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/47653566/7849549 ,I doubt the way you are sending ajax request

Comment: I have also specified the route for the post method, so I am unable to understand what needs to be done here.

Comment: @MVS There are two mistakes, please check my answers

Answer (score 0):

Try your data as in this format:

```
data:{'posa': aa, 'posb': bb},
```

and

```
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);    
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still not able to view them in the response tab.

Comment: Can i have a look of code for better understanding?

Comment: So there's nothing wrong then? You able to view the response as well?

Comment: Yup i am getting response while using your ajax request format, can not say anything about your backend code (need to check to be sure). @MVS

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a variable on ajax success like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/masterdata",
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: {aa,bb},
            success:function(response){
            console.log(response);    
       }
        ,error:function(){ 
            console.log("Error!!!!");
       }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i found two issue in your ajax request.

1. you have to change `data: {aa,bb},` to object like `data: {aa : aa, bb : bb},`
2. Your success response log is wrong. Current code `success:function()`, it should be `success:function(data)`

Full output of new code is :

```
<script>
    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        var aa=$(this).next('label').text();
        var bb=$('textarea#txt2').val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers:
                {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
        });
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/masterdata",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {aa : aa, bb : bb},
            processData: false,
            cache: false, 
            async :false,
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data);    
       }
        ,error:function(){ 
            console.log("Error!!!!");
       }    
    });
    });
    }); 
</script>
```

**To get parameter value in controller use**

```
 /**
 * Store.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $aa = $request->input('aa');
    $bb = $request->input('bb');
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this as well, but shouldn't I be able to view the data being passed here i.e aa and bb in either params/response using the developer tools?,

Comment: @MVS, how you are trying to get parameter. can you please share?

Comment: @MVS also share route you have set

Comment: Route: Route::post('/masterdata', 'MasterdataController@store');

Comment: The parameters are received through var aa,bb.

Comment: @MVS i mean in controller how you try to get parameter?

Comment: It returns me a null value.

Comment: @MVS are you able to get value of aa and bb in click event and before ajax call?

Comment: @MVS updated my answer added `processData: false,cache: false, async :false,`
please try this

Comment: Tried it, still not working, and yes, I was able to retrieve the values of aa and bb outside the ajax function

Comment: @MVS please add html to your question so we get more idea

Comment: will be adding it in sometime, sorry for the delayed reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        var aa=$(this).next('label').text();
        var bb=$('textarea#txt2').val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers:
                {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
        });
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/masterdata",
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: 'aa=test'+'&bb=test',
            success:function(){
            console.log(data);    
       }
        ,error:function(){ 
            console.log("Error!!!!");
       }    
    });
    });
    }); 
     </script>
```

Comment: What does aa=test mean here?

Comment: aa and bb is a variable and test is a string.you can also data send  to sever side like this. data: 'aa='aa+'&bb='bb,